# Incorrect GrantedQueryMemory(KB) Value in SSMS Dashboard report

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2016, ssms, sql-server-2017

Just checking by to see if someone else has witnessed the same and tried a fix or has been fixed:

**Issue**:

I ran below query on `stackoverflow2013` database

```
select
   ParentId as [Post Link],
   count(id)
from posts
where posttypeid = 2 and len(body) <= 200
  and (body like '%hank%')
group by parentid
having count(id) > 1
order by count(id) desc;
```

and when checking in SSMS dashboard report for GrantedQueryMemory the value shows around 62 GB which does not seem correct when collecting same from dmv

[image]
[image]

From dmv it shows 62 MB

[image]

It looked to me like a bug so reported [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37167289-incorrect-grantedquerymemory-kb-value-on-sql-perf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using XE to capture the query being executed by the dashboard, it just pulls the raw value from `sys.dm_exec_requests`.  Here's the query:

```
exec sp_executesql @stmt=N'
          SELECT master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(sql_handle) AS sql_handle,
          master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(plan_handle) AS plan_handle,
          case when LEN(qt.text) < 2048 then qt.text else LEFT(qt.text, 2048) + N''...'' end as query_text,
        r.session_id,
        r.request_id,
        r.start_time,
        r.status,
        r.statement_start_offset,
        r.statement_end_offset,
        r.database_id,
        r.blocking_session_id,
        r.wait_type,
        r.wait_time,
        r.wait_resource,
        r.last_wait_type,
        r.open_transaction_count,
        r.open_resultset_count,
        r.transaction_id,
        r.cpu_time,
        r.total_elapsed_time,
        r.scheduler_id,
        r.reads,
        r.writes,
        r.logical_reads,
        r.transaction_isolation_level,
        r.granted_query_memory,
        r.executing_managed_code
    FROM sys.dm_exec_requests AS r
        JOIN sys.dm_exec_sessions s on r.session_id = s.session_id
        outer APPLY msdb.sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) as qt
    WHERE s.is_user_process = CASE when @include_system_processes > 0 THEN s.is_user_process ELSE 1 END',@params=N'@include_system_processes Bit',@include_system_processes=0
```

Notice the `r.granted_query_memory` in the select, with no multiplication or division being performed on it.  Note that this number is actually in *pages.*  When I run your query I get these different numbers:

- `sys.dm_exec_requests.granted_query_memory` = 1,464 pages (times 8KB per page = 11,712 KB)
- `sys.dm_exec_query_stats.last_grant_kb` = 11,712 kilobytes
- Performance Dashboard = 11,993,088 "kilobytes"

This is *exactly* the number of bytes granted (11,712 * 1,024 = 11,993,088).

So it appears the bug is in the SSMS user interface code here, rather than in the query, as it's getting 1,464 back from the query, and must then be multiplying by 8 (conversion from pages to KB) and then 1,024 (accidental conversion from KB to bytes).  Good call reporting it to Microsoft.

I recently reported the exact same type of calculation problem to Microsoft in a Query Store report, which is documented in this Q&A: [What is 'Log Memory' in Query Store 2017](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/231682/what-is-log-memory-in-query-store-2017).  Seems like a common problem =)

Comment: Joshn@ Thanks for the confirmation, yes thats correct. When i opened the rdl file being used by performance dashboard , then the expression used makes a calculation as reported in my feedback link